# Word to define someone who makes friends easily?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives

What do you call the person who makes friends easily? The only words I can think of, are "charming" or "social", but those are not the words I'm looking for.

Someone's help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Outgoing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outgoing)

> openly friendly and responsive : extroverted
>
> - His outgoing personality made him popular at school.

Answer (score 1):

How about friendly or personable?

#### Friendly

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/friendly)

> b. Outgoing and pleasant in social relations: a friendly clerk.

#### Personable

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/personable)

> 1. Pleasantly sociable.

I'm not sure if either of these nail it exactly, but both carry some of that meaning. [**sociable**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sociable) and [**gregarious**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gregarious) might be helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

sociable, magnetic, charismatic

Answer (score 0):

**Affable**

Definition: Friendly, good-natured, or easy to talk to.